# keep me login in geckodriver selenium (java)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using selenium to automate the website. My problem is, I have to login every time while running the code, and the gecko driver opens a new tab in firefox and it fills in the login details again. is there is any other way.

code ...

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement usename = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#loginForm > div > div > div > label > input"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#loginForm > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > label > input"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    usename.sendKeys("username");
    password.sendKeys("password");
    password.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Don't know what exactly you're doing, but maybe you can use the instagram API instead? Anyway, you need to store and restore [cookies](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/). (also JavaScript is a separate and very different language)

Comment: @ChrisG im trying to create Instagram bot to like the post... is it possible to store cookies  in driver with the help of selenium??

Comment: This depends on the website under test. Couple be as simple as keeping cookies stored between runs. Might also be reusing the same browser profile

Comment: Just store the cookies in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a profile first then choose that profile and login to the site . THis stores the cookies to that profile. now use that profile.

[image]

type about:profiles and click create profile  , once created click launch browser with profile and login to that website in the new browser. Now session will be saved in that profile.

Now you can use this profile in your code:

**you can use this firefox profile as:**

**Java:**

In java you should provide profile name of the new profile:

```
    ProfilesIni profileini = new ProfilesIni();

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(profileini.getProfile("newprofile"));

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

**Python:**

in python you should give absolute root path of newprofile created:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import firefox_profile


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
  r'C:\Users\prave\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ezz3mtyg.newprofile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("url")
```

Comment: THANKS for a great reponse!

Comment: Please upvote if it helped